# Image Srcset not doing what i expected

Tags: html, css, laravel, image

hey there pretty simple question as I hope, i am trying to use image sourceset to set respo images. for testing purposes i use different images each resolution

```
<img srcset="/storage/misc_1/2020-01/c24f16f1f9465453b4f63001e5a30c20/4/c/sampleimage-300x300.png 450w , /images/forum.jpg 1199w , /storage/misc_1/2020-01/c24f16f1f9465453b4f63001e5a30c20/4/c/sampleimage-1600x1000.png 1600w">
```

the problem is: chrome decides to load the 1199w picture for almost every size and on 750px and above it loads the 1600w one , i totally dont get it. isnt it like : until 450w load 300x300, until 1199w load forum.jpg and until 1600w load 1600x1000 ?

Maybe someone can help clear up my misunderstanding.

Also, does it matter what size the actual picture has ?
the sizes for the 3 pictures in the code are : 300x300, 1199x281, and 1600x1000

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the image to change depending on the screen size, not the resolution? If so, you need to use `sizes` attribute as well -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Resolution_switching_Different_sizes

Comment: i kinda chose to go for resolution now, its better i think. thanks!